# Appium TestNG - How to identify an element in other languages

Tags: android, testng, appium, appium-android

i´m using Appium/TestNG in real devices to automate an application, but some elements have the [@text='string'] with other languages. what´s the best solution to use the same code on other languages instead of creating one code for each language ?

Comment: Best practice to use element id for multi language app.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to never use XPath locators like `//*[@text='string']`

For **Android** apps use `resource-id` or `uiautomator` locator strategies

For **iOS** apps `accessibility-id` or `ios class chain` locator strategies

It will help to keep your tests stable and reasonably fast

Comment: sorry, but i´m using XPath cause the current elements do not have id or another locator to help to have a stable test

Comment: Using accessibility-id for test automation rather than for actual accessibility is not good for the end user who relies on adaptive technology, unless the app will only be released in a single spoken language. For instance, the element locator `accessibility-id='submit'` would not be found if the runtime language is French!