# Multilingual mobile app using AccessibilityIDs for Appium - bad recipe

Tags: internationalization, appium, accessibility

My team supports a mobile app that is offered in several languages. I asked the team to implement AccessibilityIDs so that I can run Appium tests, which they did. (Why did I ask this? Because everyone in Appium testing is conveying that this is the best approach.)

Later - testing of the app's real world accessibility (using assistive technology - aka talkback or screenreader) revealed that using contextual information is desired. For example, if a button has text "Submit your order" ideally the Accessibility ID should be "Submit your order" not something like "form_page_submit_button"

The team brainstormed and the solution was to create a lang file for an obscure language that we don't plan to support. We settled on "pt-PT" so all the elements could have an accessibility ID that was not likely to change for some time.

This is now becoming a problem as I would like to have visual automated tests in English and French, not just Portuguese, and I am hoping to not have to maintain xpaths with ORs in it. For example, `//*[contains(text(),'Submit') or contains(text(),'Soumettre')]` ie, English and French.

In light of the fact that my app needs to be accessible to users more than it needs to be accessible for test script, I am evaluating which [element selector strategy](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/#selector-strategies) to recommend going forward. I am prepared to recommend using ID or name to alleviate this issue, but would like to get more thoughts on  what others are doing in this space.

Comment: May I know in which platform you are writing the scripts?

Comment: Apparently I am asking the same question as this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/39466/locator-strategy-for-list-view-elements-in-android-app.

Answer (score 0):

Going with ID's and names sort out the situation as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798383/10841478).
If you like to use the XPath then you can use a dictionary variable to store the text based on the region i.e. [EN='Submit', FR='Soumettre'] and set the locators with the text-based on the region by using the dictionary values using the region as key and appending the text to the locator i.e. framing the locator dynamically based on the region might work out.

As I worked on Robot framework, using some piece of code to depict it and using [collections](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) and [string library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html) of robot framework

```
*** Variables ***
${region}   EN                       #set this var as per region
${loc}    xpath = //*[contains(text(),'replace_text')
&{submit_loc_text}   EN=Submit
              ...    FR=Soumettre

*** Keywords ***
implementation
     ${text_asper_region}   Get From Dictionary   ${submit_loc_text}    ${region}
     ${loc}   Replace String    ${loc}    replace_text    ${text_asper_region}
     Set Test Variable    ${loc}   ${loc}
```

Comment: I did not accept this answer because I do not want to write locators based on content that is likely to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you still prefer to use accessibility ids and support all languages, I would suggest to create interface for every language to get the relevant accessibility locators. This will be easy to understand and maintain ofcourse efforts will be little more but I think it will be worth.